# I have tried using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to destroy fragments but my app still crashes?

Tags: java, android, memory, android-fragments

I have used FragmentStatePagerAdapter in order to destroy fragments when they are out of view but my app still crashes - the memory monitor shows a big peak in memory usage when I slide to my 3rd fragment and then the app crashes. I have 5 fragments in total as I'm trying to build a sound board app. Where each of the fragments is a different soundboard.

here is my mainactivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager viewpager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);
    viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
}
}
```

here is my pageradapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0) {
        case 0:

            return new FragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentThree();
        case 3:
            return new FragmentFour();
        case 4:
            return new FragmentFive();


        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 5;
}


}
```

and here is my first fragment of five:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment  {


SoundPool Clubb1;
int clubb1Id;
SoundPool Clubb2;
int clubb2Id;
SoundPool Clubb3;
int clubb3Id;
SoundPool Clubb4;
int clubb4Id;
SoundPool Clubb5;
int clubb5Id;
SoundPool Clubb6;
int clubb6Id;
SoundPool Clubb7;
int clubb7Id;
SoundPool Clubb8;
int clubb8Id;
SoundPool Clubb9;
int clubb9Id;
SoundPool Clubb10;
int clubb10Id;








@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState
) {

    Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1, 1);
    Clubb2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb2Id = Clubb2.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb2, 1);
    Clubb3 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb3Id = Clubb3.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb3, 1);
    Clubb4 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb4Id = Clubb4.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb4, 1);
    Clubb5 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb5Id = Clubb5.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb5, 1);
    Clubb6 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb6Id = Clubb6.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb6, 1);
    Clubb7 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb7Id = Clubb7.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb7, 1);
    Clubb8 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb8Id = Clubb8.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb8, 1);
    Clubb9 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb9Id = Clubb9.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb9, 1);
    Clubb10 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb10Id = Clubb10.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb10, 1);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

    Button buttonA = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    Button buttonB = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    Button buttonC = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    Button buttonD = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
    Button buttonE = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonE);
    Button buttonF = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonF);
    Button buttonG = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonG);
    Button buttonH = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonH);
    Button buttonI = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonI);
    Button buttonJ = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonJ);

    View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonA:
                    //A clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb1Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonB:
                    //B clicked
                    Clubb2.play(clubb2Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonC:
                    //C clicked
                    Clubb3.play(clubb3Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonD:
                    //D clicked
                    Clubb4.play(clubb4Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonE:
                    //E clicked
                    Clubb5.play(clubb5Id, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonF:
                    //F clicked
                    Clubb6.play(clubb6Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonG:
                    //G clicked
                    Clubb7.play(clubb7Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonH:
                    //H clicked
                    Clubb8.play(clubb8Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonI:
                    //I clicked
                    Clubb9.play(clubb9Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonJ:
                    //J clicked
                    Clubb10.play(clubb10Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonB.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonC.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonD.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonE.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonF.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonG.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonH.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonI.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonJ.setOnClickListener(ocl);

    return rootView;
}}
```

Any ideas how to stop this memory peaking and the app crashing? When I tried it with just 3 fragments the app worked perfectly fine and did not crash or lag. Now that I have added two more fragments the app crashes when you swipe to reach the third or the fourth fragment and never loads the 5th fragment. It won't let you swipe that far. Am really lost and not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the SoundPool class does not look good at all. Take a look at the following tutorial; http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-android-s-soundpool-class-a-tutorial.html

The Idea behind SoundPool is that you can have multiple samples loaded in the same pool. You should probably have One Pool for your entire application; or at max one per fragment.

Since SoundPool objects are native, you must also take care to manually call "release" on them. The official documentation says

> In our example, when the player has completed the level, the game
>   logic should call SoundPool.release() to release all the native
>   resources in use and then set the SoundPool reference to null. If the
>   player starts another level, a new SoundPool is created, sounds are
>   loaded, and play resumes.

You can create your SoundPool in the Fragment's onCreate() method, and call release in onDestroy()

You get the OutOfMemoryError because you have set the viewpager setOffscreenPageLimit to 0, that means that fragment instances are never cached. Every time you swipe left or right, a new Fragment is created with 10 new SoundPool objects that are never released.